# How to simulate flink streaming job failure scenario

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a flink streaming job inside a flink cluster. I need to simulate a job failure scenario. I have introduced a corrupted event in my source. When that event comes I see that job throwing exceptions and tasks have restarted from the checkpoint. I have set the below configurations:

```
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 1
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay: 5 s
```

But these configurations are not honoured. The task keeps recovering even after 1st attempt. According to the documents the job should be failed after 1st attempt. I need to simulate the job failure scenario. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set

```
restart-strategy: none
```

in which case the job will fail directly, without attempting a restart.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/task_failure_recovery.html#no-restart-strategy

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to create a specific job that will throw an exception each time when processing the data, for example inside of the custom `ProcessFunction`. I don't know what kind of job You have there, but another thing may be to send incorrect input data that will cause the job to fail if You are reading data from some source say Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar puzzle about this. Combine with test, I make some guesses. restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts  means retry count when restart job failed. In your case, Flink job can restart successfully, after that, a corrupted event was fetched from source and  failed the job. So task keeps recovering even after 1st attempt. You could shutdown your source or sink to simulate the job failure in that case job will restart failure attempt only once.